# Is there a way to generate html tables without paragraphs inside the cells (using docutils rst2html)?

Tags: python, html, css, restructuredtext

If I have a rst like this:

```
+--------------------------------+
| Table H1                       |
+-------------+------------------+
| Table H2a   | Table H2b        |
+=============+==================+
| a1          | b1               |
+-------------+------------------+
| a2          | b2               |
+-------------+------------------+
| a3          | b3               |
+-------------+------------------+
```

And convert it to html like this:

```
python -u %PYTHONPATH3%\\Scripts\\rst2html5.py input.rst output.html
```

The generated html table looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="document"><blockquote><table>
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 42%" />
            <col style="width: 58%" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr><th class="head" colspan="2"><p>Table H1</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr><th class="head"><p>Table H2a</p></th>
            <th class="head"><p>Table H2b</p></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><p>a1</p></td>
            <td><p>b1</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><p>a2</p></td>
            <td><p>b2</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><p>a3</p></td>
            <td><p>b3</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></blockquote></div>
</body>
```

The cell contents, as you can see, are placed inside paragraph tags (inside `<p></p>`), thus being formatted as a paragraph and not like my table is configured in a css file (eg. if I add a first-line indent to text paragraphs in the css, the cell contents also receive that indentation)

Is there a way to generate html tables without paragraphs inside the cells (using  docutils rst2html)?

Notes:

- I'm actually converting a really long rst file, so making it work properly instead of hacking/replacing the html should be preferred.
- The same thing happens with my list items, the are created inside `<p>` tags (eg. `<li><p>Something</p></li>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom CSS to override the visual spacing from the `<p>` tags.  Something like this.

```
td > p, li > p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I think it is strange, however, that your output generates `<p>` tags in tables, as that is not what docutils does, assuming that is what rst2html5 is based upon.  I would suggest you contact the author of that library.

**Edit:** Here's my HTML output using Sphinx and your reST sample:

```
<table border="1" class="docutils">
<colgroup>
<col width="42%">
<col width="58%">
</colgroup>
<thead valign="bottom">
<tr class="row-odd"><th class="head" colspan="2">Table H1</th>
</tr>
<tr class="row-even"><th class="head">Table H2a</th>
<th class="head">Table H2b</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody valign="top">
<tr class="row-odd"><td>a1</td>
<td>b1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-even"><td>a2</td>
<td>b2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-odd"><td>a3</td>
<td>b3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It solves the `real` problem (the rendering), even if the paragraphs are still there.
Maybe I should just stick with this and file a bug/issue at docutils' page.
Thanks for the css solution!

Comment: The issue should be filed with [rst2html5](https://github.com/marianoguerra/rst2html5/), not docutils. Or use rst2html, docutils, or Sphinx instead.

Comment: The rst2html5 script I'm using came with docutils (`Author: Günter Milde <milde@users.sf.net>`, `Maintainer: docutils-develop@lists.sourceforge.net`) and consists of a single .py file (`docutils.writers.html5_polyglot.__init__.py` plus a few css ones.
`rst2html5`  is just the name of the script/frontend that calls it.

Comment: I cannot replicate the extraneous `<p>` tags using Sphinx, which also uses docutils. I've edited my answer accordingly. I don't have rst2html5 installed, but I would point the finger there because it states in its [description on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rst2html5) "It is a complete rewrite of the docutils’ rst2html and uses new HTML5 constructs such as `<section>` and `<aside>`."

Comment: Right, using Sphinx also solved the problem (generated html properly / clean of unnecessary paragraph tags), so the specific rst2html5 script is the one to blame, as you've said before.

Comment: Unfortunately, the name "rst2html5" is used by both, a Docutils front end using the Docutils "html5_polyglot" writer and a 3rd party Python package.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a table cell in rST can contain more than one paragraph, for example:

```
.. list-table::

  * - 1
    - 2
  * - 3
  
      second par
      
    - 4
```

The Docutils "html5" writer always uses `<p>` tags around table cell content for better consistency and styles them accordingly in CSS.

The Docutils "html4css1" writer only uses `<p>` tags if there is more than one paragraph in the table, so using `rst2html4` instead of `rst2html5` (or selecting the "html4" writer in Sphinx's conf.py) is one way to solve the problem.

I would, however, recommend to use the "html5" writer and adapt the CSS.
(Example CSS rules can be found in Steve's answer as well as in the CSS style files that come with the Docutils source.)